# How can I verify the linear hypothesis in a multiple logistic regression using SAS?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, logistic, sas

I have a multiple logistic regression where 2 of my independent variables are continuous. The rest are dichotomous. I am supposed to verify the linear hypothesis for the continuous variables. Is there a way to do this using SAS?

Answer (score 5):

Sure, one way to do this is to introduce nonlinear terms into the model, and test their significance. A good way to do this is with regression splines. First, you need to create spline variables for your continuous predictors. This can be done using `PROC TRANSREG` or `PROC IML`. `PROC TRANSREG` offers various spline transformations, such as natural cubic splines. You will need to specify the number, and location, of knots. A common approach is to place knots at quantiles of the data distribution.  If the spline terms are statistically significant, it suggests that there might be a non-linear relationship between the continuous variable and the outcome. You should also check the model's overall fit and compare it to the linear model. And as always plotting the predicted probabilities or log odds against the continuous variable can provide a visual assessment of linearity.

`PROC IML` offers a higher degree of flexibility and control but at the cost of increased complexity. Using `PROC IML` for spline regression involves manually setting up the spline basis functions, which requires a solid understanding of matrix programming and the mathematical underpinnings of spline models. Additionally, implementing the logistic regression model itself, including the optimisation of the likelihood function, needs to be done manually in `PROC IML`. This approach provides the advantage of customisation and the ability to tailor models to specific analytical needs, but it is more time-consuming and requires advanced programming skills.

Answer (score 1):

In R:

```
require(rms)
f <- lrm(y ~ rcs(x1, 4) + rcs(x2, 5), data=mydata) # restricted cubic spline, 4 or 5 default knots
anova(f) # gives test of no linearity (separate and combined x1,x2)
```

Comment: This has been flagged as low quality, probably due to its length and OP asking for SAS. While I disagree, perhaps, Frank, you can add a bit of context to that.